# transform from one list format to key-value format in JOLT

Tags: jolt

I have one scenario where I have to transform below json

```
{ "Authenticators": [
    "ALPHA",
    "BETA",
    "GAMA"
] }
```

to

{ "availableAuth":"ALPHA,BETA,GAMA" }

Answer (score 0):

Check this spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Authenticators": "=join(',',@(1,Authenticators))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Authenticators": "availableAuth"
    }
  }
]
```